# What is the opposite of the CSS :last-of-type selector?

Tags: css

The CSS selector `:last-of-type` selects the last element of the type. Is there a way for me to select everything which comes before the last element of the type?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:not(:last-of-type)`

```css
div span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
}

div span:not(:last-of-type) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: and this is precisely what i would have answered too.

Comment: That doesn't select everything before the last element of the type unless the type being selected is also the last type in the container.

Comment: Note: you *should* be pretty specific with selectors like that since `:not(.foo)` would match  EVERYTHING that doesn't have the class `.foo` including `<html>`, `<body>` etc. This can quickly have unintended consequences if you're not careful.

Comment: Agree with @Quentin you might want `:not(:nth-last-child(1))` or `:not(:last-child)` instead.

Comment: The question is not clear enough about what he wants to do, but my answer seems to valid for this case.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the :not operator in another answer and then tried this and it worked well. Not sure if there is a performance difference.

`:nth-last-child(n+2)`